# module not found can't resolve 're-base'

Tags: rebase

I am importing Rebase from `re-base`, but its throwing an error:

> moodule not found can't resolve 're-base' in '/home/salisu/Desktop/React Projects/catch-of-the-day/src' "

**Code:**

```
import Rebase from 're-base';

const base = Rebase.createClass({
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDciFjReP_AmFD31eSPnBhRbYkaJ7L2Mqc",
    authDomain: "catch-of-the-day-salisu-a6502.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://catch-of-the-day-salisu-a6502.firebaseio.com"
});

export default base;
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense.  You have tagged it with "rebase" with is a Git version control command / concept.  But this actually seems to be noting to do with Git.  Rather it seems to be some code in a "mystery" programming language concerning some "mystery" library.

Answer (score 0):

install the re-base and also peer up it with the dependencies
Try this command my issue is solved.

npm install re-base --legacy-peer-deps